# Submodules of a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $V=\mathbb{C}^{2}$ and let $$T=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]:V \rightarrow V.$$
Consider the $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module structure on $V$ where complex numbers act by scalar multiplication and $x$ act by $T$.

(a) Find the matrix of the action of $2x^3-x+3 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ on $V$.

(b) Does the same assignment define a $\mathbb{C}[x]/(2x^2+x+1)$-module structure on $V$?

(C) Describe all submodules of $V$.

I know that for $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $V$ and linear map $T:V \rightarrow V$ we can turn $V$ in to an $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module by defining scalar multiplication by (($\sum a_{i}x^{i})v)=\sum a_{i}T^{i}(v)$ where $T^{0}(v)=v$ and $T^{i+1}(v)=T^{i}(T(v))$ and I can solve part (a) but about part (b) and (c) I don't have any ideas and I don't know the connection of part (a), (b) and (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of sheer laziness and for cleaner reading, define
$$
A := \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(2x^3 -x + 3)}.
$$
Note that in $A$, the polynomial $2x^3 - x + 3 \equiv 0$. It can be checked (!!!) that a module $M$ over the ring $A$ is equivalent to a pair $(V,T)$, where $V$ is a complex vector space and $T:V \to V$ is a matrix for which $2T^3 - T + 3 = 0$. The reason why this happens is essentially from the fact that $A$ is a quotient ring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Because modules over $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are equivalent to pairs $(V,T^{\prime})$ where $T^{\prime}$ is a matrix (no restrictions), adding the relation that defines $A$ means that you have to enforce that same relation on the matrix $T^{\prime}$ you choose when giving the pair $(V,T^{\prime})$.

With this observation, your problem (b) reduces to the following: Is it true that
$$
2T^3 - T + 3\cdot I = 0?
$$
Note that this connects to (a) because your problem (a) asks you to compute exactly this qunatity.

Finally, for your problem (c) you need to ask what it means to be a submodule. Generally, a submodule $M \hookrightarrow N$, after translating through this ''vector space and matrix'' trick becomes a function between pairs $f:(V,S) \to (W,T)$ where $T:W \to W$ and $S:V \to V$ are matrices and $f:V \to W$ is an injective linear function such that
$$
f(S(v)) = T(f(v))
$$
for all $v \in V$. This is perhaps seen via the more elegant but more abstract commuting diagram:
$$
\begin{array}
 VV & \xrightarrow{T} & V \\
 f\downarrow & & \downarrow f \\
 W & \xrightarrow[S]{} & W \\
 {}
\end{array}
$$
Let's see how this relates to your problem. For this you have
$$
(W,S) = \left(\mathbb{C}^2, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right).
$$
What you need to do is now find all vector spaces $V$ with injective linear functions $f:V \to \mathbb{C}^2$ such that the given matrix $S$ that acts on $V$ satisfies the following property for all $v \in V$:
$$
T(f(v)) = f(S(v)).
$$
Expanding this out asks you to find all $(V,S)$ for which $f:V \to \mathbb{C}^2$ is an injective linear function and
$$
f(S(v)) = T(f(v)) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}f(v)= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} f(v)_1 \\ f(v)_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} f(v)_1 + f(v)_2 \\ f(v)_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
whenever $v \in V$.